# String match in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to make separate columns in my query result for values stored in in a single column. It is  a string field that contains a variety of  similar  values stored like this:
["john"] or ["john", "jane"] or ["john", "john smith', "jane"],etc...  where each of the values  in quotes is  a distinct value.  I cannot seem to  isolate just ["john"]  in a way that will return john and not john smith. The john smith value would be in a separate column. Essentially a column for  each value in quotes. Note, I would  like the results to not contain the quotes or the brackets.

I started with:
Select name
From namestbl
Where name like %["john"]%;

I think this is heading in the wrong direction.  I think this should be in select instead of where.

[image]

[image]

Sorry about the format, I  give up trying to figure out the completely useless error message when i try to save this with table markdown.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: I suspect that you need a combination of chained `REPLACE` and `split_part`

Answer (score 0):

Your data examples represent valid JSON array syntax. So cast them to JSONB array and access individual elements by position (JSON arrays are zero based). The `t` CTE is a mimic of real data. In the illustration below the number of columns is limited to 6.

```sql
with t(s) as 
(
 values
 ('["john", "john smith", "jane"]'),
 ('["john", "jane"]'),
 ('["john"]')
)
select s::jsonb->>0 name1, s::jsonb->>1 name2, s::jsonb->>2 name3, 
       s::jsonb->>3 name4, s::jsonb->>4 name5, s::jsonb->>5 name6
from t;
```

Here is the result.

| name1 | name2 | name3 | name4 | name5 | name6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | john smith | jane |  |  |  |
| john | jane |  |  |  |  |
| john |  |  |  |  |  |